# ashx method call - make reusable

Tags: c#

i have an ashx file that creates a binary csv file for me. i'd like to be able to pass it any generic list.

i know i can put the list in session and then pick it up in the generic handler but will that acceptable under heavy loads?

```
   byte[] csvData = Utility.ToCsv(",", DAL.GetProducts());

    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(csvData, 0, csvData.Length);
```

it would be nice if i can run any query within the handler (instead of hard-coding DAL.GetProducts()). what are some ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset is above the threshold of what can be serialised into QueryString data, I would simply create a HttpHandler which accepts the list as serialised POST data. That way all your ToCsv() handler needs to do is get the list out of the post data and then deserialise it.

Let me know if you need me to elaborate on any of this.

Comment: Does that mean that I would have 2 handlers? A custom and the generic handler.

Comment: Explain exactly what you mean by generic? Do you mean a method which operates on generic data, or just a 'generic handler' as in a custom handler?

Comment: I have a generic handler (or .ashx file) that can take a generic list and export it. Is there a way to have an ashx file accept serialized Post data. And how do I serialize generic list and post it in webform?